# Tables with Hebrew text using babel

Tags: babel, hebrew

I have a document in Hebrew which I render using `babel` and now I want to add a table which includes text in Hebrew. While the entire document renders ok, in this case the text is rendered in the wrong direction (left to right instead of right to left).

I would appreciate any help (I'm also flexible moving from `babel` as long the new package is supported by Overleaf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||c |c||} 
 \hline
 טור 1 & טור 2 \\[0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem? If it did I'd thank you if you accept it. If not, please let us know so we can try and find other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

babel does not force the bidi on a tabular. You need to do that yourself. What I do is use `array` package to define a new column type to support hebrew:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\beginR}c<{\endR}}
```

And a full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\selectlanguage{hebrew}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\beginR}c<{\endR}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||C |C||} 
 \hline
 טור 1 & טור 2 \\[0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Note however this only reverses the cell, not the table. The first column is still shown at the left. The only way to get the correct order is with `luatex`.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020, `babel` supports the `tabular` option to do this for you. It requires LuaTeX and does not work perfectly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english, bidi=basic, layout=sectioning.tabular]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=2.5cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}]{Libertinus Serif} % Or any font that supports Hebrew.
\babelfont{sf}
          [Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}]{Libertinus Sans}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Ligatures=TeX]{Libertinus Mono}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

 \begin{tabular}{||c |c||} 
 \hline
 טור 1 & טור 2 \\[0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Libertinus sample]

Comment: “does not work perfectly”. Please, report any issue you find. I'm aware it's not perfect, but I need specific cases where it doesn't work. Well, at least this example seems to work .

Comment: @JavierBezos It looks to me as if the first row is typeset LTR, when it should be RTL.

Comment: It's the browser, which is mixing RTL and LTR . If I copypaste the code in an RTL editor, it's shown correctly.